# How to I separate vertices of a mesh in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Is there a way to separate the vertices of a Three.js mesh? Basically, I want to rip and tear apart a 3D object with mouse input. Recently, I wrote a GLSL vertex shader for [this web app](https://github.com/steveblue/synth) that displaces the vertices of a mesh by the brightness of a video.

I am at a loss however, at how I could select the vertices of the mesh and essentially separate it's edge from it's nearest neighbor while the vertex shader is also displacing the object.

Comment: Do you want to do that on the CPU side prior to rendering? Is http://threejs.org/examples/js/modifiers/ExplodeModifier.js what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Selecting all verticles im using simple listing:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 30, 30, 30 ,1,1,1);
for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i ++ ) {
            var vertices = [];
            for ( var v = 0; v < geometry.vertices.length; v ++ ) {
            vertices.push( geometry.vertices[ v ].clone() );
            if ( v === i ) {
                //getting only Z axis:
                //vertices[ vertices.length - 1 ].x *= 2;
                //vertices[ vertices.length - 1 ].y *= 2;
                vertices[ vertices.length - 1 ].z *= 2;
            }
            }
            geometry.morphTargets.push( { name: "target" + i, vertices: vertices } );
        }
    console.log(geometry.vertices);


//Updating the morphs with new values. We only want to influence one side of the cube
        mesh.morphTargetInfluences[0] = 1
        mesh.morphTargetInfluences[2] = 1
        mesh.morphTargetInfluences[5] = 1
        mesh.morphTargetInfluences[7] = 1
```